# Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity,

Tags: php

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.somesite.com/");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

echo $dom;
```

throws

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity,
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string in test.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 182):

To evaporate the warning, you can use [`libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)

```
// create new DOMDocument
$document = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// set error level
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// load HTML
$document->loadHTML($html);

// Restore error level
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
```

Answer (score 101):

I would bet that if you looked at the source of `http://www.somesite.com/` you would find special characters that haven't been converted to HTML. Maybe something like this:

```
<a href="/script.php?foo=bar&hello=world">link</a>
```

Should be

```
<a href="/script.php?foo=bar&amp;hello=world">link</a>
```

Comment: Just to expand on this, if the & character is even in text and not an HTML attribute, it still needs to be escaped to &amp;.


The reason the parser is throwing the error is because after seeing an & it's expecting a ; to terminate the HTML entity.

Comment: ...and to expand further, calling `htmlentities()` or similar on the string will fix the problem.

Answer (score 57):

```
$dom->@loadHTML($html);
```

This is incorrect, use this instead:

```
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

Comment: or $dom->strictErrorChecking = false;

Comment: This is a terrible solution as you will make errors on this line a nightmare to debug. @Dewsworld's solution is much better.

Comment: what is the `@` for ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php It basically suppresses errors

Comment: This is a very dirty solution and this won´t fix everything.

Comment: While your answer will work around the problem, the line "This is incorrect" is, itself, incorrect.

Answer (score 16):

There are 2 errors: the second is because $dom is no string but an object and thus cannot be "echoed". The first error is a warning from loadHTML, caused by invalid syntax of the html document to load (probably an **&** (ampersand) used as parameter separator and not masked as entity with &).

You ignore and supress this error message (not the error, just the message!) by calling the function with the error control operator "@" (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php )

```
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

Answer (score 12):

The reason for your fatal error is [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/DOMDocument) does not have a __toString() method and thus can not be echo'ed.

You're probably looking for

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 11):

Regardless of the echo (which would need to be replaced with print_r or var_dump), if an exception is thrown the object should stay empty:

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
)
```

**Solution**

1. Set `recover` to true, and `strictErrorChecking` to false

   ```
   $content = file_get_contents($url);

   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->recover = true;
   $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
   $doc->loadHTML($content);
   ```
2. Use php's entity-encoding on the markup's contents, which is a most common error source.

Comment: On the first solution you wrote dom instead of doc.

Comment: this worked for me I only added $content = mb_convert_encoding( $content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' );

Answer (score 10):

replace the simple

```
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

with the more robust ...

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

if (!$DOM->loadHTML($page))
    {
        $errors="";
        foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error)  {
            $errors.=$error->message."<br/>";
        }
        libxml_clear_errors();
        print "libxml errors:<br>$errors";
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.somesite.com/");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(htmlspecialchars($html));

echo $dom;
```

try this

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but if you ever want ot fix the malformed '&' signs in your HTML. You can use code similar to this:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
$page = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($page));
fixAmps($page, 0);
$dom->loadHTML($page);


function fixAmps(&$html, $offset) {
    $positionAmp = strpos($html, '&', $offset);
    $positionSemiColumn = strpos($html, ';', $positionAmp+1);

    $string = substr($html, $positionAmp, $positionSemiColumn-$positionAmp+1);

    if ($positionAmp !== false) { // If an '&' can be found.
        if ($positionSemiColumn === false) { // If no ';' can be found.
            $html = substr_replace($html, '&amp;', $positionAmp, 1); // Replace straight away.
        } else if (preg_match('/&(#[0-9]+|[A-Z|a-z|0-9]+);/', $string) === 0) { // If a standard escape cannot be found.
            $html = substr_replace($html, '&amp;', $positionAmp, 1); // This mean we need to escape the '&' sign.
            fixAmps($html, $positionAmp+5); // Recursive call from the new position.
        } else {
            fixAmps($html, $positionAmp+1); // Recursive call from the new position.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibile solution is

```
$sContent = htmlspecialchars($sHTML);
$oDom = new DOMDocument();
$oDom->loadHTML($sContent);
echo html_entity_decode($oDom->saveHTML());
```

Comment: This will not work. According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php, all html special characters are escaped too. Take for example this piece of HTML code `<span>Hello World</span>`. Running this into `htmlspecialchars` will produce `&lt;span&gt;Hello World&lt/span&gt;` which isn't HTML anymore. DOMDocument::loadHTML will not treat it as HTML anymore but as a string.

Comment: This works for me:
``$oDom = new DOMDocument(); $oDom->loadHTML($sHTML); echo html_entity_decode($oDom->saveHTML());``

Answer (score 0):

Another possibile solution is,maybe your file is ASCII type file,just change the type of your files.

Answer (score -1):

Even after this my code is working fine , so i just removed all warning messages with this statement at line 1 .

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ERROR); ?>
```