# PHP to get html source, then parse values within certain DIV tags

Tags: php, parsing, html

I can get the source code fine, but I now want to be able to get the data from within a specific div:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.website.com');
```

say $html contains:

```
<div class="productData">
   <div class="productDescription">Here is the product description</div>
   <div class="productPrice">1.99</div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to return the data within , and do this for all occurrences?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DOMDocument class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), combined with [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), something like this:

```
$url = 'http://www.website.com/';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'productData')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: either do this or use `preg_match` function for matching the strings and manipulating

Comment: No, [dont do that](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)!

Comment: I did try something along these lines, but I get this:
`Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : head in Entity`

Comment: What if you use the revised code (change $url to whatever you want to use)

Comment: I get: `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity`
Could this be anything to do with the page containing javascript?

Comment: Could you post the exact, full content of the URL? And are you using the exact code above, or a slight variation? (for example, echoing won't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685277/warning-domdocumentloadhtml-htmlparseentityref-expecting-in-entity)

Comment: content of url: http://pastebin.com/xM3Lr7Gk
code:
`<?php 
Thanks for your help


$url = 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtextbooks-tradein&field-keywords=test&x=14&y=14';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'productData')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    // do something
}
?>`

Comment: My bad, loadHTML should have been load() now that it is passed an url.

Comment: Now I get:
`Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: xmlParseEntityRef: no name in http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtextbooks-tradein&field-keywords=test&x=14&y=14, line: 118`

Comment: What happens if you add this line: `$dom->recover = true;` (right after `new DOMDocument()`)

Comment: I get:
`Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: xmlParseEntityRef: no name in http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtextbooks-tradein&field-keywords=test&x=14&y=14, line: 118 in /home/votefunv/public_html/amazon_test.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: EntityRef: expecting ';' in http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtextbooks-tradein&field-keywords=test&x=14&y=14, line: 118 in /home/votefunv/public_html/amazon_test.php on line 5`

The same errors as before basically

Comment: It's probably because the markup is invalid, I don't have a good answer for you on how to fix that. Try googling for `php fix invalid html` and look at [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)