# Retriving search engine results from a website without API

Tags: php, html, search-engine

I was trying something like that:

```
$url = “http://www.howtogeek.com”;

$str = file_get_contents($url);
```

That displays the whole website. It's not the website in the `$url`, and the website I'm trying to retrieve results doesn't have an API that I could use. I want to get number of results titles of results and so on. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking this in the general sense of websites without API's, or specifically about the howtogeek.com website?

Comment: in the general sense

Comment: Have a look at [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte), which will allow you to read a page and then iterate over it using XPath or CSS expressions. Bear in mind the docs are a bit light, but it is good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to use a DOM Parser like the [DomDocument class](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php). Usage:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

Then find the appropriate methods to do what you want.

You could also do it with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all.php) depending on what you want to do exactly, but it [can be next to impossible for a full webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), especially if you don't control the source yourself.

Comment: Yep, really don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. There is a [canonical answer on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/472495) about that...

Comment: that is what I've tried for now:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($url);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$resultCounter = $doc->getElementById('resultCounter');
echo $resultCounter->nodeValue;

and I got Trying to get property of non-object on last line

Comment: You still need to get the html with $html = file_get_contents($url); ibeforehand. loadHTML() does not take in a url.

Comment: $doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents($url); 

$doc->loadHTML($html);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$resultCounter = $doc->getElementById('resultCounter');
echo $resultCounter->nodeValue;

That is what i've tried right now and I get :loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity on line with loadhtml

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685277/warning-domdocumentloadhtml-htmlparseentityref-expecting-in-entity