# How I get the value of "rel" attribute from the html view source using php?

Tags: php, html, curl, html-parsing

I want the value of the *rel* attribute of the anchor tag associated with the search domain.

I have to change the domain "blog.zeit.de/berlinjournal" instead of "http://blog.zeit.de/berlinjournal/". Use this domain and find out *rel* Val

@Sam Onela, code not working for this domain. Please help me to solve this error.

My code is:

```
$domain = 'blog.zeit.de/berlinjournal';
$handle = fopen($domain, 'r');
$content = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);
if ((strpos($content, $domain) !== false)) {
        echo 'true'; // true if $domain found in view source content
}
```

Get the clear idea in blow image

[image]

Comment: is this your site? if not and you are allowed to scrape it, just use `DOMDocument`

Comment: @Ghost, Is not my site. ok, thank you ...

Comment: @Angel it appears that the HTML of the page changed so that link no longer exists. Is there a different link you can target?

Comment: Hmm I don't see any anchor tags with just the single attribute `rel="nofollow"` ... but I do see `<a href='http://rballutschinski.wordpress.com/' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Ruben Ballutschinski</a>` ... do you want to find that one?

Comment: @SamOnela, I want  rel="nofollow" value, problem is that when I search domain in HTML view source without "http://" then It will return nothing, but with http:// it will work fine.

Comment: Like I said, the HTML appears to have been updated and there are only two anchor tags with a **rel** attribute containing _nofollow_. Can you use one of those? `<a href='http://rballutschinski.wordpress.com/' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Ruben Ballutschinski</a>` or `<a href='http://www.squat-tempelhof.de/' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>wowereilusconi</a>`

Comment: @SamOnela, What you said I can't understand but my requirement is, For ex. In HTML view source I search the domain name "http://rballutschinski.wordpress.com/". it's rel value is "nofollow" so 
I want just searchable URL rel value nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance of [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), call the [loadHTML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method, then use [simplexml_import_dom()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php) to get an instance of a [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php), on which the [xpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method can be used to query for that anchor tag.

You may also notice warnings printed to the screen when loading the html. To set it to use the internal error handler, use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` - thanks to @dewsworld for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10482622/1575353).

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$results = $xml->xpath("//a[@href='$domain']");
if (sizeof($results)) {
    echo 'rel: '.$results[0]['rel'].'<br>';
}
```

See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ces9-snkm).

#### Update

Since the HTML of the original URL has changed and the requirement is now to find the *rel* attribute of a different anchor tag, that can be done with the [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) xpath function.

```
$searchDomain = 'rballutschinski.wordpress.com/';
if ((strpos($content, $searchDomain) !== false)) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($content);
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
    $results = $xml->xpath("//a[contains(@href,'$searchDomain')]");
    if (sizeof($results)) {
        $rel = $results[0]['rel'];
    }
```

See a demonstration in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ntrk-58s6).

Comment: Thanks @Sam Onela

Comment: your code is working well bt when I m using my $searchdomin = https://www.paintyourlife.com/watercolor-portraits.php and $domain = http://www.messhall.org/contemporary-watercolour-portrait-artists-who-have-changed-the-face-of-portraits/ then it will give me an error.. I put my code in https://pastebin.com/j4E7nAYQ plz help me to solve this error.. Thank you

Comment: if you are seeing another error that you are not familiar with, and don't find any documentation on it, then perhaps [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).