# How to extract some text with regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

HTML:

```
<input name="__CUTE" id="__CUTE" value="/dfdjksfhnvdj9326r" type="hidden">
```

If need the entire page I will update the post

The only thing I know is that its needs to be with preg_match:

```
preg_match('/value="([^"]+)"/'...
```

Comment: What are you even trying to extract and what u are trying to do , explain it better please.

Comment: Just change word for value in your preg_match regex

Comment: @Innervisions im trying to extract the value inside the input __CUTE, Then view it through echo.

Comment: @jeprubio But it will extract all the values that is on the page right? I want only what in the CUTE input

Comment: Give me an example what inside __CUTE needs to be extract/replaced

Comment: That seems to be XML, so use an XML parser. Of course, you could use regular expressions, but I'm pretty sure I could come up with valid and equivalent XML that your regular expressions won't cover, because it's either overcomplicated or brittle.

Comment: @Innervisions its very long value so i cut half: /wEPDwUKMTEzMTQ2NjgyOA8WAh4PaG9uZXlwb3RWZXJzaW9uBQI0NxYCZg9kFgYCAQ9kFgICGw9kFgICAQ8WAh4EVGV4dGVkAgUPZBYSAgEPFgIeB1Zpc2libGVnFgICAQ8PFgQfAQUDMTAxHgdUb29sVGlwBRRiYWxhbmNlOiAxMDEgc2F0b3NoaWRkAgMPFgIfAmdkAgUPFgIfA

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes, a little complicated. I've attached a response above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use DOMDocument for this but since you want to use a regexp expression:

```
$res = preg_match('/<input name="__CUTE" (.*?) value="([^"]+)"/s', $html, $matches);
```

And get the value of the **second** match only.

In case you want to use DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$cute = $dom->getElementById("__CUTE");
echo $cute->getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: Works for me with a DOM better :) Thanks a lot! But how do i make it pull just one line? its gives me 4 lines

Comment: Do you mean new DomDocument()->loadHTML($html)->getElementById("__CUTE")->getAttribute('value') ?

Comment: I fixed the warnings with the help of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685277/warning-domdocumentloadhtml-htmlparseentityref-expecting-in-entity thank you:)