# How to parse element within element by class name?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domxpath

How to select any element inside specific element tag by class. I need to retrieve attribute "name" value from "input" element that inside element "form". In example. there're 2 forms elements named _arrived and _class. I need to retrieve all attribute name value from form `_class`

```
   $source = '
    <form method="post" action"arrived.php" class="_arrived">
    <input type="hidden" name="type1" value="value1" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="type2" value="value2" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="type3" value="value3">
    <input type="hidden" name="type4" value="value4">
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="destiny.php" class="_class">
    <input type="hidden" name="type1" value="value1" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="type2" value="value2" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="type3" value="value3">
    <input type="hidden" name="type4" value="value4">
    <input type="hidden" name="type5" value="value5">
    <input type="hidden" name="type6" value="value6">
    <input type="hidden" name="type7" value="value8">
    <input type="hidden" name="type8" value="value9">
    </form>';


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($source);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('//form[@class="_class"]');

 $form = $items->item(0);

 $element = $form->getElementsByTagName("input");

 foreach($element as $elemen){
     foreach($elemen as $value){
         echo $value->getAttribute('name').'<br>';
     }
 }
```

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie no result just output white blank page.

Comment: `action"arrived.php"` is invalid, you should be getting `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in Entity`

Comment: Apart from that do:- `foreach($element as $elemen){
    echo $elemen->getAttribute('name').'<br>';
 }` you will get names

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie: I think OP wants all attributes, so another loop over `$elemen->attributes` is needed.

Comment: @Amadan What is it means? that error? and how to solve that?

Comment: It means that your HTML is bad. `action"arrived.php"` should be `action="arrived.php"`.

Comment: Furthermore, you could simplify by a couple of lines - there is no need for both XPath and `getElementsByTagName`, you can get what you want just with this XPath: `'//form[@class="_class"]/input'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.First you have to iterate over `$elements` one time

2.You have to use `action="arrived.php"` instead of `action"arrived.php"` to remove warning from your code which is:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in
>   Entity, line: 2 in /in/tl53u on line 24

Do like below:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($source);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('//form[@class="_class"]');

 $form = $items->item(0);

 $element = $form->getElementsByTagName("input");

 foreach($element as $elemen){
    echo $elemen->getAttribute('name').'<br>';
 }
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/Ma8bg

You can ignore warnings by using `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`, but best is to solve them. Check reference below:-

[Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10482622/4248328)

Comment: Problem is that the HTML isn't always under their control, it is more likely the result of code elsewhere and unfortunately resorting to `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` is a common thing.

Comment: @NigelRen  agreed. But at least OP can look to the code once to see if he found any issue at first glance or not? We cannot blame others when we are doing copy-paste business. It's our responsibility to solve all issues coming after copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have loops on the elements? This should work:

```
...

$elements = $form->getElementsByTagName("input");

foreach($elements as $e){
  echo $e->getAttribute('name').'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have only single loop

```
foreach($element as $elemen){
    echo $elemen->getAttribute('name').'<br>';
 }
```

and you will get all name attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the actual name attribute from the input elements directly rather than having to go through several calls to different methods and then just loop over them and output the text content.

Here the XPath expression first selects the form your after and then will pick out each input element and finally using `@name` will select the name attribute...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($source);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//form[@class="_class"]//input/@name') as $value){
    echo $value->textContent.'<br>';
}
```