# How To Fetch images from a website and store in mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, simple-html-dom

Hi I want to get all images from a website and store it on MySQL using PHP I am using HTML dom its showing me an error please help me here is this error

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 73 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Oifind\Formula.php on line 3

and here is my code

```
<?php 
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $src= $image->getAttribute('src');
    echo "<img src='".$src."'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You want to get all of the images from http://www.google.com/? Do you have permission to store them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685277/warning-domdocumentloadhtml-htmlparseentityref-expecting-in-entity)

Comment: It's probably not UTF-8 compliant. Joyitiarun what encoding is your PHP file?

Comment: I dont know sir